# How to pass an subclass argument to another subclass in multiple inherited class in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to use multiple inheritance and I don't know if it's just me using it badly or if there's a clean way to do what I'm trying to do.
Here's my code :

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, b_x: int, **kwargs):
        self.b_x = b_x
        super().__init__(c_x=self, **kwargs) # /!\ Problematic line


class C:
    def __init__(self, c_x: B, c_y: int):
        self.c_x = c_x
        self.c_y = c_y


class A(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(b_x=3, c_y=4)


a = A()
```

here's the MRO :

```
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class 'object'>]
```

The thing is the linter is sending me this error :

```
error: Unexpected keyword argument "c_x" for "__init__" of "object"
```

That I understand correclty but I want to know how to deal with it.
What's working for me is to do this instead :

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, b_x: int, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.b_x = b_x
        kwargs["c_x"] = self
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

But I'm not really satisfied.

The code is working fine but I'm just trying to be more explicit in the class B because I know the C class will need this specific argument. How can I do that ? Should I do everything in the A class where I know all the logic or is there another way ?

Comment: Can you give an example with some actual context? B isn't actually related to C except via A, it shouldn't have to know that much about it. And C gets self _as self_ anyway. In general you handle multiple inheritance with kwargs, for the specifics you'd need to be more specific.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to get rid of a builder that include the B instance inside the A class like that :
def a_builder(b_x, c_x, c_y):
    A(b_x, c_x, c_y)
by just making A inherit from my B class.

Comment: That doesn't make a great deal of sense as a refactor, but again there's no context from which to make sensible suggestions.

Comment: Maybe I'm just overcomplicating things and I should just do 
in A(C): super().__init__(c_x=B(), c_y=4)
maybe it's clear enough

Answer (score 1):

If I specify the class names when calling the constructors and call them both from sub-class, I get around the error.

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, b_x: int, **kwargs):
        self.b_x = b_x
# line that reported error no longer needed

class C:
    def __init__(self, c_x: B, c_y: int):
        self.c_x = c_x
        self.c_y = c_y


class A(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
# call B's constructor and then C's constructor
        B.__init__(self, b_x=3, c_y=4)
        C.__init__(self, c_x=self, c_y=4)  # c_x is supposed to be an instance of B.
```

If you call `super().__init__` from a class with no explicitly specified super-class, it should, if the instantiated class has other super-classes for which `__init__` has not yet been called, call the `__init__` on the other super-class. That's what you were trying to achieve. However, the arrangement that you had effectively mandated that the class has another super-class that took 2 parameters.